# Not sure how to evaulate this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

The Limit
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{8+h} -2}{h}$$
represents the derivative of some function $f$ at some number $a$. find such a function and a suitable number $a$.

so If do the conjugates I get (assuming I did it right):

$$\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{8+h-4}{\sqrt[3]{8+h}+2}$$

However, when I checked the answer it was: $f(x) = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and $a$ was equal to $8$

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  The main thing for inputting formula is to enclose them in dollar signs if you want them inline, e.g. "\$x\$" gives $x$, or double dollar signs if you want them on their own line, e.g. "\$\$x\$\$" gives $$x$$ I have tried to set the formula you wanted, if I have got it wrong please change it back.

Comment: Multiply by the conjugate of the numerator, $(8+h)^{1/3}+2$ to remove $h$ from the denominator. Or, are you familiar with L'Hopital's formula?

Comment: awesome thanks @David I still new to the whole 'math code' thing

Comment: @MitchKnight somewhat I know it exists, but haven't really employed it before.

Comment: The question **does not** ask you to *evaluate* the limit. I would probably give the answer $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{8+x}$, and $a=0$. But $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}$, $a=8$ is correct. We want our expression to look like $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you better explain because I am not sure what you mean? or at least a source so I can learn or better yet re-learn what I am guessing I am overlooking.

Comment: Andre is right. You need to set it in the form of a derivative, which looks like what he has shown. The actual function itself can be $\sqrt[3]{x+c}$ with $a=8-c$

Comment: It is a question of writing down the **definition** of the general function $f(x)$ at $x=a$. Then find $f$ and $a$ so that you get a match with your expression. The answer by Matthew has one such matching. There are others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f'(x ) = \lim_{h\to 0 } \frac{ f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ \sqrt[3]{8+h} - 2 }{h}$. So it appears that we want $f'(8)$, giving us $f(8)=2$. By comparison, it seems natural to choose $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x}, a=8$.

Comment: Okay, to make sure I understand this correctly, sorry for the mild uhhh "dullness"  on my part, but, are you saying essentially that the only way to make $\lim_{h \to 0}\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{8+h} -2}{h} = 0$ is to make x = 0 as Andre suggesting in his answer or in context to the question to make $\sqrt[3]{x} = 2$ is make $x=8$ correct?

Answer (score 0):

For your limit, note the conjugate multiplication done is not correct.  $$\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{8+h} -2}{h} \frac{(8+h)^{2/3}+2(8+h)^{1/3}+4}{(8+h)^{2/3}+2(8+h)^{1/3}+4} \to \frac{1}{12}$$ which of course is the same as $f'(8)$ if $f(x) = \sqrt[3]x$.